# Finding keywords in text by sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use Python to search keywords in sentences. I found one coding provided by Chris_Rands is really helpful, but I would like to change the output format. Here is the code and its output, followed by what I would like the new output to look like.

Can you suggest changes to the code to create the new output?

**Original code from Chris_Rands**:

```
sentences = "My name is sing song. I am a mother. I am happy. You sing like my mother".split(".")
search_keywords=['mother','sing','song']

for sentence in sentences:
    print("{} key words in sentence:".format(sum(1 for word in search_keywords if word in sentence)))
    for word in search_keywords:
        if word in sentence:
          print(word)
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

Chris_Rands's output:

```
2 key words in sentence:
My name is sing song

1 key words in sentence:
 I am a mother

0 key words in sentence:
 I am happy

2 key words in sentence:
 You sing like my mother
```

I am wondering how to print those "keywords" in the outcome, so the outcome will look like this:

**Desired Output**

```
2 key words in sentence: sing song
My name is sing song

1 key words in sentence: mother
 I am a mother

0 key words in sentence:
 I am happy

2 key words in sentence: sing mother
 You sing like my mother
```

Comment: You need to (1) learn Python (2) understand what the given code does (3) think about how your program should work (4) write your code.

Comment: Seriously, questions _like this_ are too broad (and off-topic) for [so] because it's not clear what part of the solution can't you understand, and we can't copy and paste the whole Python documentation into the answer.

Comment: Did the below answer help? If so, feel free to accept, or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by appending to a newly defined list for each sentence.

**Solution**

```
for sentence in sentences:
    lst = []
    for word in search_keywords:
        if word in sentence:
            lst.append(word)
    print('{0} key word(s) in sentence: {1}'.format(len(lst), ', '.join(lst)))
    print(sentence + "\n")
```

**Result**

```
2 key word(s) in sentence: sing, song
My name is sing song

1 key word(s) in sentence: mother
 I am a mother

0 key word(s) in sentence: 
 I am happy

2 key word(s) in sentence: mother, sing
 You sing like my mother
```

**Explanation**

- Define a new list for each sentence.
- Use `list.append` to append where a word is matched.
- Use `str.format` to print the output in the desired format.